# Execute php script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am building a php application. In a script, there is a call to execute a jar file:

```
?php
exec('java -jar simulations/simulation.jar');
?>
```

The problem is that this command line executes the jar file:

```
user@ubuntu: php execSimulation.php
```

but not the call from the web page. The call is made by AJAX, am I missing something??

```
<!-- Script to execute the simulation -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
        <script>

            function sendRequest() {
                new Ajax.Request("ejecutarSimulacion.php", 
                    { 
                    method: 'post', 
                    postBody: 'name='+ $F('name'),
                    onComplete: showResponse 
                    });
                }

            function showResponse(req){
            alert(req.responseText);
            }
        </script>

<form id="test" onsubmit="return false;">
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $simulacion; ?>" name="name" id="name" >
                                <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" onClick="sendRequest()">
                            </form>
```

When I try to print only the param I send, for instance, the alert shows it, so I am sure that the call is reaching the the server, but I don't know why the jar file is not executed. Any ideas, please?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Error trace:

```
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:62)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:142)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:385)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:438)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:384)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:174)
    at org.opensourcephysics.tools.TranslatorTool.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.opensourcephysics.tools.TranslatorTool.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at org.opensourcephysics.display.OSPRuntime.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.opensourcephysics.controls.OSPLog.fine(Unknown Source)
    at org.opensourcephysics.tools.ResourceLoader.addSearchPath(Unknown Source)
    at _users.tanqueCalentamiento.TanqueCalentamiento.<clinit>(TanqueCalentamiento.java:18)
Could not find the main class: _users.simulation.Simulation. Program will exit.
```

Comment: On ubuntu there a different php.ini config files for apache and cli. Do you have safe mode enabled in your /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini or is there a value in "safe_mode_exec_dir"...?

Comment: Google claims this is the solution to the X problem: export DISPLAY=:0 (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-0-0-as-the-value-of-the-display-variable-178234/)

Comment: The solution you mentioned on your second comment, doesn't make any change. In my php.ini I can find this line: safe_mode_exec_dir =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your jar requires an X server to be running.

> Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

When you run it from command line, do you have X running?  If you do, this would explain why it works there, and not from PHP.

You can try to "hijack" the running X session from PHP.

```
exec('DISPLAY=:0 java -jar simulations/simulation.jar');
```

You may have to first run `xhost +localhost` (or `xhost +`) from the command line, to allow the user PHP is running as to connect to X.

Comment: 22 goddamn seconds!  I swear, one more bad beat like this one and I'm taking hostages.

Comment: And you really should write `exec('DISPLAY=:0 java -jar simulations/simulation.jar');`

Comment: I am not very sure about what X server is. I'll look for information. Anyway, exec('DISPLAY=:0 java -jar simulations/simulation.jar'); is not executiong jar file :(

Comment: X sever is GUI for linux systems.  When you run it from command line, you're running it from a terminal window (you have a desktop), right?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the answers. Yes, I'm using a terminal window, where it executes the jar file. But not from the php script

Comment: Now the error says: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. Which is the right value?

Comment: mujeresponja@ubuntu:~$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host

Comment: @Rocket let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2587/discussion-between-blanca-hdez-and-rocket)

Comment: Would I make things in a different way on Windows?? I am running the same process and it stays blocked: I tryed to remove 'DISPLAY=:0', try to get an error trace, but the process is just blocked. Thanks again

Comment: I don't know how do to this on Windows, sorry.

Comment: Just to let you know: in Windows is necessary to start/stop xampp server as administrator

Answer (score 2):

In the immortal words of Jamie Savage, "There's yer problem."

The Java program you're running is trying to get to your X Windows "server" (i.e., the screen) on initialization, which works when you're running from the command line but not from the headless web-server.  Talk to the people who wrote org.opensourcephysics.tools.TranslatorTool about how to disable this (grossly dysfunctional) behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path in exec() : base paths are different between the CLI SAPI and the apache one.

```
 <?php 
 exec('full/path/to/jar');
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I tried, but the same result: exec('java -jar /opt/lampp/htdocs/blanca/simulations/simulation.jar');

Comment: is the php file in the same folder than the webpage which loads the script ?

Comment: Yes. both of them are in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blanca/ then, the jar files in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blanca/simulations

Comment: The path to the java executable should also be made absolute. `/usr/bin/jre/java` or whatever it happens to be.

Comment: The jar is not ecexuted with this command: exec('/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java -jar /opt/lampp/htdocs/blanca/simulations/simulation.jar');

Comment: Please, check the edit in my question, maybe the probelm is clearer for you. Thanks