# Execute php script (Windows)

Tags: php

A few days ago I published [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097553/execute-php-script/7098161#7098161), and it was solved succesfully on Unix.

Now I moved  to Windows and I have the same problem.

I need to execute a command from the web application. It must execute a `.jar` stored in the system. I looked on Google and found some changes that I needed to do.

The function to execute the command is:

```
<?php
if($_POST["name"] == "")
    echo "name is empty";
else{
    $path = $_POST["name"];
    //$command = 'DISPLAY=:0 java -jar '.$path'; -> Used in Unix
    //$command = 'java -jar ../../../../simulaciones/tanqueCalentamiento.jar';
        $command = 'java -jar ..\..\..\..\simulaciones\tanqueCalentamiento.jar';
    //system($command);
    exec($command);
}
?>
```

The comments are different options I have tried. `$path` is the argument, but  decided to put directly the path, to clarify my question:

**Do I need a kind of "trick" as I did for Unix?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows vista, 7 (I don't know if in others too), there is a problemm with xampp.

The apache does not stop, doesn't matter what you do, even switch the computer off. At least for me, the solution was:

1. Uninstall xamp and reinistall it.
2. Start/stop it always as administrator:

   path\xampp\xampp_start
   path\xampp\xampp_stop

Right click: run as administrator.

In this way apache is finished properly, and I can run my command with no probleems anymore

I hope this helps
http://drupal.org/node/224342

Answer (score 2):

The one I use:

```
function _exec($cmd)
{
   $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
   $oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0,false);
   error_log($cmd);
   return $oExec == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

/!\ If your application has an interface, and if you are using vista or 7, your server can't be run as a service!

Comment: My applicacion has an interface and I am using 7... I used your function and it returns 1. As I don't understand very well your code, I don't know neither what it really means... Sorry, completely newbie in this field...

Comment: The application has probably been launched, but you can't see it. Which server are you using? apache, IIS?

Comment: At least now the process ends, before it was just stack. I'm using apache, do you need more information??

Comment: Actually I have the apache running in a xampp server

Comment: Try to uninstall the Apache service, and then, launch manually apache. Then, check again if it's working.

Comment: @Blanca WScript.Shell provides direct access to the shell via COM, I have mentioned it previously [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093510/exec-waiting-for-a-response-in-php/7093638#7093638) with links to the official docs which explain what it does/how it works.

Comment: @Blanca Are you trying to launch a GUI app here?

Comment: @Whiler +1 for being someone who actually knows how to use COM to launch programs asynchronously. I have seen so many ugly solutions involving 20 calls `start` and other horribleness...

Comment: Yes.. She is... she should start apache from the user, not from the _session Console_

Comment: BTW, as it returns 1, this means it works as expected. The issue is only linked to Windows' sessions.

Comment: With xampp, you should have a file like this somewhere: \xampp\apache\apache_uninstallservice.bat

Comment: @Whiler If you like PHP/have lost the file, you can also do it with [win32service](http://php.net/manual/en/book.win32service.php). Obviously, it is a PITA to have to manually start Apache everytime - could you start it with a scheduled task set to run as the user, with 'Only run if logged on...' checked? Or does this still launch in such a way that it wouldn't work?

Comment: It's strange, because I can not stop apachee. Not using Ctrl+C in the console (I started it using xampp_start), not from the control panel. I even restarted my computer and it was already running... could be the problem here?

Comment: @DaveRandom: Personnally, I use the _Windows tasks scheduler_... with the trigger on _session open_ (and as I have an autologin, it starts when my computer starts ;o) ; But let's see if Blanca can get his java application works from a manual start before the next step ;o)

Comment: @Blanca: Open the services (run _services.msc_) and find apache or xamp (I don't have xamp.. don't really now how it manages all the stuff (apache, mysql, ..) ; then stop the apache service.
 If you can't, stop the process Apache.exe (with the task manager).

Comment: :) Thanks. If I type: java -jar C:\xampp\htdocs\blanca\simulaciones\tanqueCalentamiento.jar it is executed with no problem

Comment: ok... but.. if you stop the apache service... uninstall the apache service (just this service, not xamp), and then launch apache manually... when you call your webpage, does it work?

Comment: I can not stop apache, not even uninstall it, no even uninstall xampp. The  reason is that I have a process running (apache) and no permits to stop it. Not even as runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd

Comment: Do you see the Apache service when you run _services.msc_? If yes, could you edit it and choose _Desactivate_ for its start? If no, I don't have any more ideas ;o(

Comment: Aftter restaarting my computer several times, I managed to kill apache process. Then I uninstall the whole xampp server, installed again, but the result is the same... :( I'm still getting 1 fromj your function, but the jar file is not execute. Thanks again

Comment: and does Apache starts as a service? if yes, this could **not work** better... it must **NOT** start as a **service** as you have a **GUI**

Comment: The problem was how I was starting xampp. i post an answer to clarify it better, Thans for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

You're just starting 'java'. That means that the Java executable (java.exe) must exist, and must be able to be executed. Since you don't specify a path, it must be in a directory that is in the %PATH% environment variable.

To test, simply start cmd and type `java<enter>`. If java gets executed, you'll know at least you'll have java installed and startable. If it doesn't, check if you have java and specify the correct path to the java executable.

You can also run the `.jar` from the command line to see if it works. If it works like this, it is likely to work in PHP too.

Comment: I have jaava installed, and if I run thee same command  it runs with no problem. Then I guess, the problemm must be in another  place...